# Taking out common data

Tags: sql

I want to compare two column and take out the common rows which are present in table1 and table 2 from two different tables.

```
table 1          table 2             result 
mobnum A         mobnum B            988123456          
988123456        988124567201718     988123457            
988124567        988123456201718        
944123456        988623456201718
```

Comment: your data is unclear, post your sample result as well.

Comment: `select column_1 from table_1 intersect select column_1 from table_2`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure since you haven't really formated your data in a nice way but I think the code below will give you what you want, I included the second table in the where () in order to only select matching values. If you need the rows simply change "Select Num" to Select the unique Id's and go from there.

Table Test_1:

```
Num
988123456
988124
988124567
944123456
```

Table Test_2:

```
Num
988123456
988123457
9881234
9886234
```

Query:

```
select Num from Test_1 where Num in (Select Num from Test_2)
```

Output:

```
Num
988123456
```